# Backup issue DirectAdmin - Centos 7

Tags: centos, php

In Centos 7 + DirectAdmin i have a problem when i wan to make a backup from all users as ADMIN.

Error Message :

```
Error while backing up database admin_USER1
Error while backing up database admin_USER1: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/admin/backup/admin_USER1.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect


<18:34:04>
Error while backing up database RES_USER2
Error while backing up database RES_USER2: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/ken/backup/RES_USER2.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect

Error while backing up database RES_USER3
Error while backing up database RES_USER3: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/ken/backup/RES_USER3.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally DirectAdmin keep MySQL user/pass in `/usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf`.

But, in DirectAdmin + CentOS 7, there is another MySQL (user/pass) file in
`/usr/local/directadmin/conf/my.cnf`.

Check this file !